# How to make an arc with same data different colors?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have an arc divided equally into 10 of the same value data,

I want to color each differently.

I think sgroup.selectAll(".arc") will go through 1 arc at a time and fill it with "#123", can I create a function that returns an array of the colors that I want?

How would I do this?

```
var data = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10];
var width = 1000;
var height = 1000;



var canvas = d3.select("body")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("height", height)
               .attr("width", width);

var colorScale = d3.scale.category10()
              .range(["red", "blue", "orange","red", "blue", "orange","red", "blue", "orange","red"])
              .domain([0,12]);

var group = canvas.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(500,500)");

// arc radius
var radius = 300;
var p = Math.PI *2; //full circle

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius-100)
            .outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function (d){return d;});

var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc);

group.selectAll(".arc")
     .attr("fill", "#123");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HBPM4/

Comment: Unless you plan to add more properties to your data which you can base the colors on, you can simply color them by index, using `.attr("fill", function(d,i) {return color(i)});`. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fbj6S/). You can customize the color scale I used by specifying `range` and `domain` like you have in your code above.

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect. One more question, where are the values of the colors coming from in the cateory10?

Comment: It is [in-built](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales)...when you customize you use an ordinal scale for colors, like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390971/d3-refining-ordinal-scale-to-return-groups-of-colours#10392571).

Comment: From the docs...category 10: Constructs a new ordinal scale with a range of ten categorical colors: #1f77b4 #ff7f0e #2ca02c #d62728 #9467bd #8c564b #e377c2 #7f7f7f #bcbd22 #17becf.